# Live search not working on appended rows of table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table defined that has one pre-defined row and new rows can be created on clicking a button that calls this function:

```
function newProduct()
{

var table=  document.getElementById("producttable");
//var table = trow.parentNode;
var clone = table.insertRow(-1); 
clone.insertCell(0);
clone.insertCell(1);
clone.insertCell(2);
clone.insertCell(3);
clone.insertCell(4);
clone.insertCell(5);
clone.insertCell(6);
clone.insertCell(7);
clone.insertCell(8);
clone.cells[0].innerHTML='<input type="text" class="form-control" name="psku[]" value="0"  />'
clone.cells[1].innerHTML='<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname[]" value="" /><div class="result"></div>';
clone.cells[2].innerHTML='<input type="number" class="form-control" name="pqty[]" value="0"  onkeyup="calcCost(this);" />';
clone.cells[3].innerHTML='<input type="number" class="form-control" name="pcp[]" value="0" onkeyup="calcCost(this);" />';
clone.cells[4].innerHTML='<input type="number" class="form-control" name="ptp[]" value="0"  />';
clone.cells[5].innerHTML='<input type="number" class="form-control" name="ptax[]" value="0"  onkeyup="calcCost(this);" />';
clone.cells[6].innerHTML='<input type="number" class="form-control" name="pdisc[]" value="0"  onkeyup="calcCost(this);" />';
clone.cells[7].innerHTML='<input type="number" class="form-control" name="pfp[]" value="0" />';
clone.cells[8].innerHTML='<input type="checkbox"/>';
table.appendChild(clone);   
}
```

Now I want to conduct a live search on product name for which I am using JQuery. This is the snippet that performs the search.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#producttable tr').each(function(){
    $("td").eq(1).find(":input").on("keyup input", function()
    {
    var prodname = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(prodname.length)
    {
        //get input value on change
        //document.write(prodname);
        $.get("product-search.php", {term: prodname},function(data)
        {
            // Display the returned data in browser
            //document.write(resultDropdown.className);
            if(data== "null")
                resultDropdown.empty();
            else
                resultDropdown.html(data);
        });
    } 
    else
        resultDropdown.empty();

    });
```

This query works fine for the forst pre-defined row, i.e., if i type something on product name field, it gives a corresponding list of suggestions. But it does not  work for the new rows that are appended. How can I access the product name cell of the table using JQuery?

Comment: you will have to re-attach the onKeyUp handler after adding the new rows and inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#producttable').on('keyup input', 'tr td input', function(){
    var prodname = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");

    if(prodname.length) {
      //get input value on change
      //document.write(prodname);
      $.get("product-search.php", {term: prodname},function(data){
        // Display the returned data in browser
        //document.write(resultDropdown.className);
        if(data== "null")
            resultDropdown.empty();
        } else {
            resultDropdown.html(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      resultDropdown.empty();
    }
  });
});
```

Hopefully this works, since `#producttable` always exists, then you just need to put a click handler on it, and the 'tr td input' will make sure the code will only run when an input is clicked, now you don't need to manually add event handlers each time you add a new row

Comment: Thanks! It does work. So i understand it works because result class is attached only to product name cells in my table. If i decide to attach it to another cell, say sku, the search would run for that as well. It would be helpful if I could access the product name cell for every row from JQuery.

Comment: `var name = this.name` ?

Comment: If you onle want the first `td` to be clickable, yes, maybe put a class on it in stead like `<td class="first-td"></td>` then you can write `$("#producttable").on("keyup input",'.first-td input', function(){`

Comment: Yeah..forgot to check by adding multiple rows. Thanks for pointing out. Solved it by adding a  name to the result class with the product name cell, and then `var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result[name='pres[]']");` Seems to work fine.